# How to print a full line of text that is inside of a variable if a string match in that line with python?

Tags: python, string, match

I have a variable with some lines of text and i want to print only that lines that have that specific string with python, how if I'm grep command but with python, and don't, I don't want to save the text in a file and then parse it and print that line, I want to do this in memory, you know, only using the variable.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code you tried so far?
Or at the very list what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry @AndiDomi I haven't code because I'm searching an option for do this anyway i have a solution but i want something more flexible, I'm just searching options for use the best, anyway thanks for you time man, you're my hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# the string you want so search from
some_string = 'first line /n second line'

# split the string into a list divided by '/n' (enter) 
some_string = some_string.split('/n')

# print the lines that have a specific word
word = 'second'
for line in some_string:
    if word in line:
        print(line)
```

An example would be something like this.
You can modify it at your will so it could fit your problem better